# Help me please, restore a deleted Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, copay, bitpay

While cleaning the memory on the phone, I accidentally deleted the wallet and the backup copy of Bitcoin Wallet.

I tried to re-download the wallet, restore deleted files (backup), but it was useless.

All I have left of my wallet is my account number and backup password.

Account number: bc1q3wv607l25uymxudl4r0ueg359zq4r92llkyf53

Please help resolve this situation. I'm ready to thank you financially.

Best regards Alexander from Ukraine

[image]

Comment: Which wallet were you using? Try connecting your phone with a computer and scan for recovery of deleted files if possible and data is not overwritten (recuva helps sometimes). It's not account number but a bitcoin address.

Comment: The number  bc1q3wv607l25uymxudl4r0ueg359zq4r92llkyf53 is a Bitcoin "address", is is not an account number. You cannot use an address to recover access to your wallet or to regain control over money associated with that address.

Answer (score 3):

If you have made a backup of the seed words given by the original wallet, you should be able to simply restore them.

If you do not have a backup, your only hope is to immediately turn off the device and contact a forensic recovery specialist who can attempt to recover the original wallet file.

Unfortunately, this will likely cost significantly more than the 0.02 BTC or so in that wallet.